# Using 110V-120V appliances in Europe (230V)

Tags: power

I wish to use American designed 60 Hz  110 V appliances in Europe with a 220 V 50 Hz supply.

I have a transformer that can convert the voltage and supply sufficient power to run the devices. Are there any other problems that I need to consider in powering these appliances? Some of them may include motors.

Comment: 50 Hz vs 60 Hz.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it didn't, but is there anything unusual about the blender?  110 vs 120 is no big deal, but I suppose the blender may really need 60 Hz...

Comment: It's not just voltage, it's also frequency. Some motors don't work well with 50Hz instead 60Hz, and you can't understand why...

Comment: Normally it is written on the plug, device or stated in the manual. Most devices can handle both ranges (it will be stated as a range, e.g. 110-250V(AC), if it is usable for 220-250V you can assume the frequency is not a problem for Europe neither, and same for 110VAC elsewhere.

Comment: This is a disguised good question. It contains issues which can give rise to good answers which will help the wider community. jumping on it and closing it is premature in my opinion. I have not checked for duplicates, if they exist that would be a valid reason for closing it.